# SQL blob modification with regexp

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, blob

I have a table with a blob column containing serialized data like this:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:69:"http://example.com/uploads/program/13/image1.jpg";
i:1;s:69:"http://example.com/uploads/program/13/image2.jpg";
i:2;s:69:"http://example.com/uploads/program/13/image3.jpg";}
```

I need to subtract 3 from each `s:[0-9]{2}`. How can this be accomplished for the whole table in MySQL?

Comment: I think it's the best lesson about normalization you've had yet.

Comment: @zerkms I did not design this database... :(

Comment: It will be much easier to do that outside mysql with any programming language

Comment: This is **PHP** serialised data, so do your processing **in PHP**. It'll save you a lot of headaches

Comment: Regexp in MySQL is used for searching, it doesn't allow making replaces.

Comment: @Devart Ok, thank you, I'll code something then.